# How to import xterm into NodeJS

Tags: node.js, xtermjs

I want to use xterm in NodeJS app but it doesn't work. I am using node version v16.15.0, npm version v8.5.5, xterm version 4.18.0.
In documentation (https://github.com/xtermjs/xterm.js), it says importing is made by writing new ES6 syntax with `import Terminal from 'xterm';`. I am also adding `"type": "module"` into package.json, but I am getting: `ReferenceError: self is not defined` showing some line in `xterm.js`.

My source code:

```
import Terminal from 'xterm';
const path = require('path')
const express = require('express')
const dotenv = require('dotenv')
const morgan = require('morgan')
const exphbs = require('express-handlebars')
const session = require('express-session')
const WebSocket = require('ws')

const wss_dashboard = new WebSocket.Server({ port: 7070 })
```

my package.json:

```
{ 
  ...
  "type": "module",
  ...
}
```

How can I fix that?

Comment: The README says Xterm.js is a front-end component. What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

You should try reloading your Node.js server and run the file again.

Adding "type": "module" to the package.json worked for me.

Also try adding {} tho the import:

```
import { Terminal } from 'xterm';
```

Answer (score 0):

Your import is not correct

Should be

```
import { Terminal } from 'xterm';
```

Not

```
import Terminal from 'xterm';
```